# Create different textviews for list of strings

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a class which I use a camera to point at an object and get all the strings it can see on the object. I then pass the list into this intent so the user can choose a specific string which I will then use to send to another activity.

However, I want to create a new textview for each string and then put an OnClickListener on each of the textviews, but I am unsure on how I can put an OnClickListener on a textview that I won't know exist as it will be created depending on the list.

```
public class SelectProductName extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<String> getString = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_product_name);
        getString = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("stringList");

        LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R.id.layout_select_product_name);
        for (int i = 0; i < getString.size();i++){
            TextView text = new TextView(this);
            text.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            text.setText(getString.get(i));
            System.out.println(getString.get(i));
            ll.addView(text);
        }
    }
}
```

So for example: getString is {"Chicken","Pie"}

I want a textview to be created for each string.

I'm unsure on how I would get the name of the textview to add the OnClickListener to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the listener just like you would do with any view:

```
LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R.id.layout);
for (int i = 0; i < getString.size();i++){
    TextView text = new TextView(this);
    text.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    text.setText(getString.get(i));
    System.out.println(getString.get(i));
    ll.addView(text);
    text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // your code goes here
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: if I create a new textview each time for each word in the list, will it overwrite?

Comment: No it will not overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SelectProductName extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener{
ArrayList<String> getString = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_product_name);
    getString = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("stringList");

    LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R.id.layout_select_product_name);
    for (int i = 0; i < getString.size();i++){
        TextView text = new TextView(this);
        text.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        text.setText(getString.get(i));
        System.out.println(getString.get(i));
        ll.addView(text);
        text.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
public void onClick(View view) {
    TextView tv = (TextView)view;
    Log.i("clicked", tv.getText().toString());


  }
}
```

Comment: yeah I know how to do that, but if I have list of words "potato" , "pie", "chicken" , I am trying to make a new textview for each of those words, how can I add the onClick to all those textviews?

Comment: the code i already wrote here will add onClick to all those textviews created in the for loop.
you can wrote your login inside the onclick method and differentiate between textview by "text"('potato', 'pie') or by a tag you give for each one while the creating operation using setTag method